# Four Fast PWM outputs, in parallel

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, pwm, transistor, arduino-duemilanove

I need four Fast PWM signals for four different transistors.

I want to use timers 1+2 (pins 3, 11, 9, 10) so it wouldn't interfere with `delay(...)`.

I tried setting the timers to Fast PWM mode, and applied different OCRnA/OCRnB values, but nothing really worked - at most, I managed to get two good PWM signals, *one from each timer*.

How should I deal with `TCCRnA/TCCRnB, OCRnA/OCRnB` to achieve 4 parallel PWM signals?

My latest attempt:

```
// Timer 1 Fast PWM setup: TOP=0x00FF, Update of OCRx at BOTTOM (0), TOV Flag Set on TOP
pinMode(9, OUTPUT); pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1) | _BV(COM1B1) | _BV(WGM10);
TCCR1B = _BV(WGM12) | _BV(CS11) | _BV(CS10); // Divisor 64
// Timer 2 Fast PWM setup: TOP=0xFF, Update of OCRx at BOTTOM (0), TOV Flag Set on MAX (0xFF)
pinMode(3, OUTPUT); pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
TCCR2A = _BV(COM2A1) | _BV(COM2B1) | _BV(WGM21) | _BV(WGM20);
TCCR2B = _BV(CS22); // Divisor 64
// ...
int val = 200; // Desired PWM output
OCR1A = val;
OCR1B = val;
OCR2A = val;
OCR2B = val;
```

Comment: You should keep the timers running to max. Not make them reset when the timer value is reached. This way it will reach both values.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code. Note that there are two fast-pwm options. One that overflow at MAX and one that overflows at OCRnA.

Comment: Added example code. I tried many combinations, this is one of them.

Comment: That's a [snippet](http://snippets-r-us.com/) - Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then we can try to help you.

Comment: That's all there is to it. The code was simply copied from my `setup()` function.

Regardless - I think the question is clear enough even without code examples - **How should I deal with TCCRnA/TCCRnB, OCRnA/OCRnB to acheive 4 parallel PWM signals?**

Comment: Double check the fast PWM selection. Does this actually use OCRnA/OCRnB?

Comment: What do you mean by "parallel"? Same frequency? Same duty cycle? Can you clarify why you don't just use one timer and route it to 4 transistors?

Comment: `My latest attempt:` - what does that attempt do? What do you want it to do, that it does not do?

Comment: You've put a bounty on the question, but don't seem interested in clarifying what the question is, exactly. No-one has attempted to answer, which maybe tells you that the question is vague. Even if you sketch on paper (and scan) or do a simple line-art drawing, that would help to clarify what "4 parallel PWM signals" means.

Comment: I want to drive four separate motors on a quadcopter, and thus the need for four separate and identical signals.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your question comes down to this:

"How to generate two PWM signals with only one timer."

(Once you've got that figured out, you could set up 6 PWM channels)

Keep in mind that there also are PWM generator IC's, if you don't want to use up all your timers, which can be usefull for other things.

IF you really want to set all outputs to toggle at the same time (based on your code example) why won't you just use one PWM signal, and drive all the 4 devices with the same signal? (Given you're not going to change it)
IF you're going to drive motors, why would you need 4 different PWM signals? It's often enough to only use one PWM signal for the right tires/tracks and one PWM signal for the left tires/tracks.

---

**Setting the max**

Since we want to generate different PWM signals from one timer, we can't just make the timer overrun (and generate a pulse or switch polarity at that point).
We want to let the timer run to completion over and over, and only change the signal when it reaches a set value.

The datasheet tells us this:

> The TOP value can be assigned to be the fixed value 0xFF
>   (MAX) or the value stored in the OCR0A Register. (328P datasheet 15.2.1 Definitions)

**Setting a limit per pin**

We want to set 2 limits on one timer, each timer has an output compare register (OCR), the action will be generated when the timer hits this value.

> The Timer/Counter (TCNT0) and Output Compare Registers (OCR0A and OCR0B) are 8-bit registers. Interrupt
>   request (abbreviated to Int.Req. in the figure) signals are all visible in the Timer Interrupt Flag Register (TIFR0).
>   All interrupts are individually masked with the Timer Interrupt Mask Register (TIMSK0). (328P datasheet 15.2.2 Registers)

**Extra info on compare**

Below you can read some extra info on the signaling.
What actually will happen, depends on how the WGM

> 15.5 Output Compare Unit
>   The 8-bit comparator continuously compares TCNT0 with the Output Compare Registers (OCR0A and
>   OCR0B). Whenever TCNT0 equals OCR0A or OCR0B, the comparator signals a match. A match will set the
>   Output Compare Flag (OCF0A or OCF0B) at the next timer clock cycle. If the corresponding interrupt is
>   enabled, the Output Compare Flag generates an Output Compare interrupt. The Output Compare Flag is
>   automatically cleared when the interrupt is executed. Alternatively, the flag can be cleared by software by writing
>   a logical one to its I/O bit location. The Waveform Generator uses the match signal to generate an output
>   according to operating mode set by the WGM02:0 bits and Compare Output mode (COM0x1:0) bits. The max
>   and bottom signals are used by the Waveform Generator for handling the special cases of the extreme values in
>   some modes of operation (”Modes of Operation” on page 98).

**Fast PWM**
The actual settings are different per mode/modus, but for fast PWM we have:

```
Table 15-3. Compare Output Mode, Fast PWM Mode(1)
COM0A1 COM0A0 Description
0      0      Normal port operation, OC0A disconnected.
0      1      WGM02 = 0: Normal Port Operation, OC0A Disconnected.
              WGM02 = 1: Toggle OC0A on Compare Match.
1      0      Clear OC0A on Compare Match, set OC0A at BOTTOM, (non-inverting mode).
1      1      Set OC0A on Compare Match, clear OC0A at BOTTOM, (inverting mode).
```

The table tells us we need to set COM0A1 and COM0A0 to 1.

```
COM0B1 COM0B0 Description
0      0      Normal port operation, OC0B disconnected.
0      1      Reserved
1      0      Clear OC0B on Compare Match, set OC0B at BOTTOM, (non-inverting mode)
```

This table tells us we need to set COM0B1 and COM0B0 to 1.

**WGM mode**

If it's all set up, we only need to put the PWM in the right mode.

```
Mode WGM02 WGM01 WGM00 Timer/Counter TOP  Update-OCRx TOV-on
0    0     0     0     Normal        0xFF Immediate   MAX
1    0     0     1     PWM,P-Correct 0xFF TOP         BOTTOM
2    0     1     0     CTC           OCRA Immediate   MAX
3    0     1     1     Fast PWM      0xFF BOTTOM      MAX
```

So we'll need to set WGM02 to 0 and WGM01 and WGM00 to 1, to use fast PWM.F

**Succes?**

You should now be able to change the PWM's of these pins by setting the output compare registers of these.
Getting the double PWM of the other timer ready, shouldn't be much more different.
Be sure to set the right prescaler. Though it depends on a lot of external things.